# Obj orientation programming - accessing names from another class

Tags: python

Methods:

– Constructor takes in no argument.

– get_stock_names(): returns a list of strings that represents the names of
all food items in the stock.

– has_stock(name): returns True if a food item’s name is found in stock.

– load(food): add the food object to stock.

– sell(name): returns the item to be sold. The item to be sold is the first
food item in the stock list that matches the input name. Remember to
remove the sold food item from stock. If the item name does not match any
in the list, return None.

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self,name,nutrition,good_until):
        self.name = name
        self.nutrition = nutrition
        self.good_until = good_until
        self.age = 0

class FermentedFood(Food):
    def __init__(self,name,nutrition,good_after,good_until):
        super().__init__(name,nutrition,good_until)
        self.good_after = good_after
```

These are previously defined

```
class VendingMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = []
    def load(self,food):
        self.obj.append(food)
        return self.obj
    def get_stock_names(self):
        return [i.name for i in self.obj]
    def has_stock(self,name):  # This part is wrong
        return  str(name) == self.obj
    def sell(self,name): # This part is wrong as well 
        if str(self.name) == self.obj:
            self.obj.remove(self.name)
        else:
            return None    


machine = VendingMachine()
apple = Food("apple", 70, 7)
banana = Food("banana", 100, 4)
yoghurt = FermentedFood("yoghurt", 50, 0, 10)
machine.load(banana)
machine.load(apple)
machine.load(yoghurt)
machine.load(apple)
print(machine.get_stock_names())  #["banana", "apple", "yoghurt", "apple"])
print(machine.has_stock("apple"))
print(machine.sell("apple")) #True
print(machine.get_stock_names()) ##Since apple is sold so `["banana", "yoghurt", "apple"]`
```

So what is wrong with `has_stock` and `sell`  ?

Comment: So, like, what's the question?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have edited already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is wrong with has_stock and sell?

```
def has_stock(self,name):  # This part is wrong
    return  str(name) == self.obj
```

You check if `str(name)` is equal to `self.obj`, which is a list. You want to check if the `name` you pass in is in `self.obj` which is a list of `Food` that have names. You will want to change it to something like this:

```
def has_stock(self, name):
    return name in [x.name for x in self.obj]
```

This makes a list of the names of the `Food`s and checks if the name you pass in is in that list.

---

```
def sell(self,name): # This part is wrong as well 
    if str(self.name) == self.obj:
        self.obj.remove(self.name)
    else:
        return None
```

You make a similar mistake here, comparing  a string to a list. Another mistake is that `self.name` does not exists. Should change that part to:

```
def sell(self, name):
    for food in self.obj:
        if food.name == name:
            self.obj.remove(food)
            return food
    return None
```

This will loop over the food list. If it finds a `Food` which name matches the name you passed in, it will remove the `Food` from the list and then return it (I'm not sure why you would want to return that though, but that's up to you). If it found no matches, the code continues past the loop and will `return None` as you wanted.

This was the result I got:

```
['banana', 'apple', 'yoghurt', 'apple']
True
<__main__.Food object at 0x00000000029CBB38>
['banana', 'yoghurt', 'apple']
```

Comment: Didn't work for the case when machine.get_stock_names() I get [] then machine.load(banana) give me None  @Tim

Comment: It works for me so I'm not sure what's up with that. Maybe better to post a new question